# comparing session attributes with null

Tags: java

This is my `Login.jsp` page, i have a String variable called `LoginSuccessfull` To determine that user logs in successfully or not.

I know that this varible returns `null` but i cant recognized by `if` condition:

```
String LoginSuccessfull = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("LoginSuccessfull"));
if (LoginSuccessfull==null || LoginSuccessfull.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
     //Print something
} else {
      //print something
}
```

I got `NullPointerException`.
What is wrong?

Comment: are you getting null pointer exception somewhere in the logs?

Comment: it is not a good practise to check for login in JSP pages this way. You should really use declaraive security or filters for separation of concerns.

Comment: @eckes Your mean is to use a `servlet` instead of `jsp`?

Comment: @user3808021 Declarative security like http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncby/index.html

Comment: I really dont know why this question is up voted twice. The detail provided is lacking for the most part to the problem, if got an exception, where is the stack trace? Did you initialize the `session` variable yet or not? Only you know

Answer (score 1):

`String.valueOf((Object)null)` will return `"null"` not `null`. It is probably best to skip this conversion entirely (is it a String or a Boolean?).

If you want to keep the conversin, check for null first, or compare with "null".

```
Object loginFlag = session.getAttribute(FLAG);
if (loginFlag != null)
{
   String loginFlagStr = String.valueOf(loginFlag);
   if ("Yes".equalsIgnoreCase(loginFlagStr))
   {
     // yes
   } else {
     // not yes
   }
} else {
  // null
}
```

BTW: it is not clear where you get a NullPointerException in your code. I suspect that in your case the only place could be `session` which is `null`. You did not show this part of your code. (if you use `getSession(false)` this can happen.)

Answer (score 0):

If session attribute "LoginSuccessfull" is not present then you will get NullPointerException by your statement `String LoginSuccessfull = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("LoginSuccessfull"));` Since you are trying to pass null to `String.valueOf` method. and by this, neither of your further checks and code is going to get executed.

Instead you could do something like:

```
Object LoginSuccessfull = session.getAttribute("LoginSuccessfull");
if (LoginSuccessfull!=null && ((String)LoginSuccessfull).equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
// do something
}
```

Comment: No this does not cause a NPE, valueOf(null) is specified to return "null". (you often use this instead of toString() as it is safe).

Comment: It does not throw NPE, it returns the string "null". This is from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29) "if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.". And there is a if (obj == null) in valueOf() for this: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk7/jdk/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#2902 . It never uses the String constructor (but toString()).

Comment: you need the Object variant, getAttribute() does not return char[] type. Beside you proved yourself wrong as you wrote: "This does returns null".

Comment: You must have a very strange java on your machine, @almasshaikh :)
http://ideone.com/e4v9BU

Comment: See for a non-NPE result: http://ideone.com/e4v9BU
The (more specific) char[] variant is only used if you specify a literal null, it is not used when you specify an object attribute with value null (as it is returned by getAttribute()).